# Javafx 2 - multiple view in a anchorpane

Tags: animation, javafx-2

I would like to show an animation with two views - overview and closeup view in a same anchorpane.

The overview would show trucks travelling from point A to point B on a map background and the closeup view would show what is happening at point B (i.e. discharging cargo etc...). When we start the animation both the views should be in action.

I am not sure how to implement this in Javafx-2. I have created an AnchorPane called globalpane and have two children - (AnchorPane)overViewPane and (AnchorPane)closeViewPane. I have got the overview pane working. But to implement the close up view, can we make a copy of overViewPane, zoom it using scale method and present it in closeViewPane?

What is the best approach to do this ?

Thanks

Ps : I found this link which shows magnifying glass:
 [Why is my magnifying glass not following the mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916364/why-is-my-magnifying-glass-not-following-the-mouse)

However, I am not sure if the same would work with animation running in the overview will also be updated simultaneously on the magnifying glass

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything regarding reflecting/copying/mirroring a same anchorpane twice. Therefore, I had to resort to coding them individually in my program.